# Most recommended automated way for conduction university exams

Tags: exams, teaching-assistant

In most of the universities of India, conducting exams such as mid terms and end terms for a semester is as follows:

1) Designing question papers and taking print of them

2) Distribute it among students along with answer sheets

3) Invigilating during exams and taking attendance

4) Collecting answer sheets

5) Evaluation and rechecking if any student has issues

This process is tedious and most of the part is unproductive.

I want to know the method for conduction exams so that less human intervention is needed.

Does any good universities in any country automated these process of conducting exam and what are the steps in their method?

Answer (score 3):

Conducting assessments with larger and larger cohorts of students is an interesting problem and many possible approaches can be tried, but some are more suitable to some subject disciplines than others.

As already mentioned multiple choice tests are one such technology. They could be computerised quizzes using, perhaps, a VLE (Virtual Learning Environment) or even an online free survey tool. There is also optical scanning of answer sheets for computerised marking of paper quizzes, but my experience shows it has limitations. Writing good multiple choice questions is a skill that needs to be acquired.

There is also peer assessment: getting the students to mark each others papers. Often more effective that you'd expect. This can be done on paper or electronically. When done electronically it can handle anonymisation and also multiple moderation.

You also need to reflect on the goal of assessment. What is it trying to achieve? Are you measuring rote learning memory or understanding and application of knowledge? Sometimes group and team tasks which are assessed by portfolio or presentation can achieve the same goals and deliver less marking burden.

You mention mid-terms. One should also question what function they serve. In many places they are only part of a carrot-and-stick approach to motivate learning and not for the assessment result. In this case they can be substituted with other forms of task which perform the same motivation function in student engagement.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid the designing question part or having them checked / verified for quality, constistency etc

But you could try an online system which offers questions from a question bank.

On good systems there are a variety of question types available: multiple choice, short answer, calculation, matching, even essay, etc

I suggest you find out what systems are out there and choose one that suits your needs.

I did build a spreadsheet that gave 5 questions out of 5 sets of 5 questions at random : worked very well for a small quiz...